# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero” exception. Why does it occur?

Tags: java, exception, rsa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero” exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483181/javax-crypto-badpaddingexception-data-must-start-with-zero-exception)

I am trying to separate the usage of the encrypt and decrypt methods into two different classes. However, I encountered the abovementioned exception while I was decrypting a string.

Below is my code:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class EncryptAndDecrypt {

/**
 * 
 */
    public static Cipher createCipher () throws Exception{            
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");            
        return cipher;    
    }    

    public static KeyPair generateKey () throws  NoSuchAlgorithmException{  

          KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance ("RSA");           
          keyGen.initialize(1024);           
          KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
          return key;   
    }
     public static byte [] encrypt (String  str, Cipher cip, KeyPair key) {      
             byte [] cipherText = null;    
              try {           
               byte [] plainText = str.getBytes("UTF8");         
               cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key.getPublic());       
               cipherText = cip.doFinal(plainText);         
               }    
          catch (Exception e) {        
            e.printStackTrace();     
    }     
          return cipherText;  
      }
     public static String decrypt (byte [] c, Cipher cip, KeyPair key) throws Exception {    
               cip.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key.getPrivate());     
               byte [] decryptedPlainText = cip.doFinal (c);// exception occurred here    
               String decryptedPlainStr = new String (decryptedPlainText, "UTF8");       
               return decryptedPlainStr;   
       }

     }

  // A separate class that uses the encrypt method in EncryptAndDecrypt
 public class EncryptionApp {


    public static void main (String [] args) {     
        System.out.println (getEncrypted());   
        }  
    public static byte [] getEncrypted () {    
        byte [] encyptedByte = null;       
        try {        
            String plainText = "hello";         
            Cipher cip = EncryptAndDecrypt.createCipher();     
            KeyPair key = EncryptAndDecrypt.generateKey();         
            encyptedByte = EncryptAndDecrypt.encrypt(plainText, cip, key);    
            String str = new String (encyptedByte, "UTF8");
            System.out.println (str);
            }       
        catch (Exception e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();    
            }         
        return encyptedByte;  
        }
    }
  public class DecryptedApp {

/**
 * A separate class to use the decrypt method in EncryptAndDecrypt
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
     System.out.println (useDecrypted ());   
     }   
 public static String useDecrypted () {   
    String decryptedText = null;      
     try {       
         Cipher cip = EncryptAndDecrypt.createCipher();      
         KeyPair key = EncryptAndDecrypt.generateKey();   
         byte [] encrypted = EncryptionApp.getEncrypted();
         System.out.println (encrypted);
        decryptedText =  EncryptAndDecrypt.decrypt(encrypted, cip, key)  ;

     }     
     catch (Exception e) {        
         e.printStackTrace();      
         }    return decryptedText;    
 }
```

}